# WMI documentation for AntivirusProduct c#

Tags: c#, wmi, antivirus

I am attempting to find the property names for the "select * from AntivirusProduct" statement when using c#.

I am wanting to find info like company / vendor / any other details about the AntivirusProduct entry - however I cannot find the documentation to find what to do i.e "select company from AntivirusProduct"

Can somebody please help me find this documentation!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it :

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=6430f853-1120-48db-8cc5-f2abdc3ed314&displaylang=en

And use the CMI tool that this installs :)

Comment: No longer available on 2019/07/08.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en) (from Microsoft) - it's helped me several times in the past find what I wanted regarding WMI classes/namespaces.

Hope it helps!